# SSL Connection in R or R Studio on Windows 10

Tags: windows, ssl, r, rstudio

I was wondering if anyone has connected to an SSL secure host via R or R studio? I've tried several different options but none have been successful.

yaml configuration file:

```
sslmode = TRUE/ALLOW/REQUIRE
sllmode = verify - ca
```

I do not have access to the server.

I'm running the following code in R Studio:

```
db <- dbConnect( dbDriver('PostgreSQL'), user = 'username', password = '*******.', dbname = 'dbname', host = 'host', port = 1234, sslmode='verify-full' )
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : unused argument (sslmode = "verify-full")
```

Reading through this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-ssl.html, I think I need figure out how to enable libpq on my local machine to get the handshake to work with the database needing the ssl connection.

I also ran the following this in R Studio:

```
db <- dbConnect( dbDriver('PostgreSQL'), user = 'USERNAME', password = '*****', dbname = 'DBNAME?ssl=true', host = 'HOST', port = 1234 )
```

My entire R Studio session fails.

Now I've run the following in R Studio:

```
con <- dbConnect(dbDriver('PostgreSQL'), dbname = 'dbname=DBNAME sslmode=require', host = 'HOST', port = 1234, user = 'USERNAME', password = 'PASSWORD')
```

This gave me the following error message:

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : RS-DBI driver: (could not connect host on dbname "dbname": sslmode value "verify-full" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in )
```

I've installed and enabled the following packages:

- DBI
- RPostgreSQL
- tidyverse
- dbplyr
- ggplot2
- openssl
- lubridate

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).